# How to read this regression table?

Tags: econometrics, regression

The image is from Abhijit Banerjee's Legacy of Colonial Land Tenure Systems[image: Abhijit Banerjee]

Comment: You forgot to upload the image

Comment: @NicolasTorres Thanks! I have updated it now

Answer (score 0):

For example, on average, non-landlord districts have 0.065 (units of area) of oilseeds more than landlord districts, keeping everything else constant. Similarly, for the other variables.

For the area share of rice, it’s the other way around since the difference coefficient is negative.

Since $\log(Population)$ is the log of a variable, we interpret its difference as:

“On average, non-landlord districts have $0.088\%$ less people than landlord districts, keeping everything else constant.

The amount of stars indicate if the Hypothesis Tests for the coefficients are significant at different $p$-values. The more stars a coefficient has, its significance hypothesis holds for higher $p$-values. Intuitively, this means the coefficients are more likely to actually not be $0$ in "real life".

If you don't really know what Hypothesys tests are, I suggest you study that topic.

The mean column is just the average value of that "category" among all your data.

The standard deviation column calculates the sample SD on all your data.

Comment: Thank you so much! If you're free could you please answer my latest and the last question too? Thanks a ton

Comment: @Nemi I just left a comment on that question as it is not clear to me what do you want to do in that one. Don’t forget you can accept and upvote my answer if you found it helpful :)